# Declaring types not used in web methods with JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Java WebService method that for performance reasons need to return a big object list in zip mode to a .NETCF application. The wsdl is generated automatically from Tomcat.
I have implemented this code:

```
@WebService
public class WS {
  @WebMethod
  public byte[] getData () {
    // Get Data object list
    List<Data> list = getDataFromDatabase();
    Data[] arr = new Data[list.size()];
    list.toArray(arr);

    // Compress data
    byte[] zipData = getZipData(arr);
    return zipData;
  }
}
```

The problem is that Data object is not declared in the wsdl and when in .NETCF program unzip the result, it can't resolve the type. So, I have implemented this other method in WebService:

```
@WebMethod
public Data[] getData () { ... }
```

Now, .NETCF knows the existence of the Data object because it appears in the wsdl generated, but I don't use this method for anything.
Is there any way or annotation for declaring Data object in Java WebService code without use a method.? For example:

```
@WebService
public class WS {
  @WebType
  public Data;

  @WebMethod
  public byte[] getData () { ... }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html), your byte array should be mapped to a `base64binary`or a `hexbinary` type. 
To include a complex type in `wsdl` file (actually it will be put in an `xsd`, which is referenced in the `wsdl`), I added the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation to class definition. For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
...
}
```

The `xsd` should contain a declaration of that class containing all fields.

But if you are returning a `byte[]` from your method, I don't see how declaring the `Data` type will help. You have to look for a mapping from the return type to something you can use in your client.

Comment: I follow this steps: when I have the Data object in Java WebsService, I serialize it to XML, then transform the XML String to byte[] and finally zip this bytes and send. When .NETCF receive the byte[], unzip to get the original XML and deserialize to Data object. If Data object is not published in wsdl, .NETCF can't deserialize it.